# What is Ruby doing in this line?

Tags: node.js, ruby, syntax

I'm trying to convert some software from Ruby to Node.js. I came across this and was curious on exactly what Ruby is trying to do:

```
// set the files variable
    this.files = Dir["C:/folder/log/app.log*"]
// sort the files by last modified date/time
    my_dir = this.files.sort_by { |file| File.mtime(file) }
// Copy the files. Not sure what the [-1] is for
    my_dir.each do |filename|
    copy_files(filename, my_dir[-1])
```

So I get that they want to copy the files to a new directory, but what is the [-1] doing?

Comment: What is `this`? Ruby does not have such a method. If `this` is from Rails you need a Rails tag.

Comment: I was converting from Ruby to Node.js. This particular snippet was mid-conversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Negative indices are relative to the end of the array, so `array[-1]` is the last element in the array.

Example:

```
a = %w(This is the end)  # => ["This", "is", "the", "end"]
p a[-1]                  # => "end"
p a[-2]                  # => "the"
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!